XMLWorkerHelper: Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag link , While converting html to pdf in ASP.NET MVC & C#
It is throwing exception

Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag link

But I have closed all the html tags properly, what is causing this exception? How to fix this?
HTML:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<html>");
sb.AppendLine("<head>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<meta charset='utf-8'>");
sb.AppendLine("<title>Image Art Challenge (IAC) 2024 | IMAGE Group</title>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1' />");
sb.AppendLine("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' />");
sb.AppendLine("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />");                         
sb.AppendLine("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='black' />");                         
sb.AppendLine("<link rel='shortcut icon' href='~/images/favicon.ico' />");                         
sb.AppendLine("<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400..700&family=Montserrat:wght@100..900&family=Roboto&display=swap' rel='stylesheet'>");
sb.AppendLine("</head>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<body style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px;'>");
sb.AppendLine("<div id='container' class='bg-white' style='font-family: Montserrat, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>");
sb.AppendLine("<div class='certificate-cont' style='width: 1056px; height: auto; margin: 0px auto; background: url(\"https://imagegroup.in/mail/certificate-bg.jpg\") no-repeat top center; background-size: 100% auto; box-sizing: border-box;'>");
sb.AppendLine("<div style='padding: 33px 35px 20px 35px;'>");
sb.AppendLine("<div class='header'><img src='https://imagegroup.in/mail/certificate-head.png' style='width:100%; display:block' /></div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<div class='content' style='text-align: center;'>");
sb.AppendLine("<h1 class='cert-title' style='font-size: 21px; color: #009a9f; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 38px; margin: 0px; padding: 16px 0px 11px;'>Certificate of Participation</h1>");                         
sb.AppendLine($"<p class='cert-txt' style='font-size: 14px; color: #6a3e25; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; padding: 13px 0px 2px;'>This is to certify that</p>");                         
sb.AppendLine($"<div class='cert-name' style='width: 615px; margin: 0px auto; font-size: 34px; border-bottom: 1px solid #6a3e25; color: #010101; line-height: 47px; margin-bottom: 20px; font-family: Dancing Script; font-weight: 700'>{participantName}</div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<div style='text-align: center; margin-bottom: 17px;'>");                         
sb.AppendLine($"<p class='cert-txt' style='font-size: 14px; color: #6a3e25; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; padding: 17px 0px 0px; line-height: 28px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>participated in the</p>");                         
sb.AppendLine($"<div class='cert-category' style='width: 295px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 8px 0px 0px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500; border-bottom: 1px solid #6a3e25; color: #010101; line-height: 28px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>{category}</div>");                         
sb.AppendLine($"<p class='cert-txt' style='font-size: 14px; color: #6a3e25; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; padding: 17px 0px 0px; line-height: 28px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>category of our nationwide</p>");                         
sb.AppendLine("</div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<p class='cert-txt' style='font-size: 14px; color: #6a3e25; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; padding: 13px 0px; line-height: 28px;'>IMAGE ART CHALLENGE held in 2024.</p>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<p class='cert-txt' style='font-size: 14px; color: #6a3e25; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; padding: 17px 0px; line-height: 28px;'>Your artistic dream for India will be cherished!</p>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<div class='cert-group-ceo' style='margin-top: 26px;'><img src='https://imagegroup.in/mail/certificate-group-ceo.png' style='width:100%; display:block' /></div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("</div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("</div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<div class='footer' style='background: #009da2; height: 28px; line-height: 26px; padding: 2px 35px; text-align: center;'>");                         
sb.AppendLine("<a href='https://imagegroup.in/' target='_blank' style='letter-spacing: 2px; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;'>www.imagegroup.in</a>");                         
sb.AppendLine("</div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("</div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("</div>");                         
sb.AppendLine("</body>");                         
sb.AppendLine("</html>");                          

string strContent = sb.ToString();

C# code to convert HTML to PDF and save it in a folder:
string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/PDFs/");

if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}

string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "-" + maildata.PARTICIPANT_NAME + "Certificate.pdf");

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f))
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        doc.Open();

        // Ensure a page is added to the document
        doc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));

        using (var sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
        {
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, sr);
        }

        if (doc.PageNumber == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("The document has no pages.");
        }

        doc.Close();
    }

    // Save PDF from MemoryStream to file
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, ms.ToArray());
}

